# PostgreSQL - query joining data from two tables with one-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in my database.

1. `companies` table with basic information about the company

```
| column_name   | data_type                |
| ------------- | ------------------------ |
| created_at    | timestamp with time zone |
| rating        | real                     |
| company_id    | uuid                     | primary key
| verified      | boolean                  |
| claimed       | boolean                  |
| street        | text                     |
| tags          | ARRAY                    |
| contact_phone | text                     |
| contact_email | text                     |
| website_url   | text                     |
| category      | text                     |
| subcategory   | text                     |
| zip_code      | text                     |
| name          | text                     |
| country       | text                     |
| logo          | text                     |
| city          | text                     |
```

2. `reviews` Table that stores reviews of all companies

```
| column_name | data_type                |
| ----------- | ------------------------ |
| company     | uuid                     | foreign key relation to company_id in companies
| trust_score | smallint                 |
| created_at  | timestamp with time zone |
| id          | bigint                   |
| title       | text                     |
| review      | text                     |
| user        | text                     |
```

Now what I want to achieve is to get information from both of these tables as a single data set, where all reviews are added as an array set to a respective company.

I am a total beginner in SQL, so I've tried to find similar case on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find one described clear enough so that I could understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what you described with a simple inner join query:

```
SELECT r.*, c.title FROM reviews r INNER JOIN companies c ON c.company_id = r.company ORDER BY c.id
```

Note that this needs to be processed after getting fetched, to do your appropriate mapping for reviews and companies.

Bonus: If you focus about companies and want to see all including those who do not have reviews you can select from companies table and use a left join or select from reviews table using right join. Same thing goes for reviews if you want all of them including those not related to any company. That is the SQL join principles, you can educate yourself about them.

Please, let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    companies.company_id,
    companies.rating,
    reviews.trust_score
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN reviews ON
    companies.company_id = reviews.company
```

You can use this to access the columns from both tables as though they were in the same table.

Here's an explanation of how the LEFT JOIN works:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-left-join/

If you use an INNER JOIN instead, then any companies with zero reviews *will disappear* from the output.

When a company has more than one entry in the `reviews` table, you'll get multiple rows back from the query.

For example, if the company with "company_id": 1 has two reviews, then you'll get two rows back:

```
{"company_id": 1, "companies_rating": 5, "trust_score": 4}
{"company_id": 1, "companies_rating": 5, "trust_score": 5}
```

If a company with "company_id": 2 also has a review, then you'll get **three** rows back:

```
{"company_id": 1, "companies_rating": 5, "trust_score": 4}
{"company_id": 1, "companies_rating": 5, "trust_score": 5}
{"company_id": 2, "companies_rating": 3, "trust_score": 3}
```

All rows with the same `company_id` will have the same company information (e.g. the same `companies_rating`), but different review information (e.g. a different `trust_score`).

As you process these rows in your code, use the `company_id` to group the information for a single company together, building up a reviews array for the company as you go.